# Javascript - Create a Regular Expression that gets all tags with any ID in an Array

Tags: javascript, regex, match

Lets say for *example* I have a string:

```
varString = "<tr><td ID=''>Hypothyroidism</td><td ID=''>10/31/1998</td><td ID=''>Active</td><td ID=''>UNKNOWN</td><td ID=''></td></tr>";
varString += "<tr><td ID=''>Cataract</td><td ID=''>6/5/2005</td><td ID=''>Active</td><td ID=''>UNKNOWN</td><td ID=''></td></tr>";
```

where I then split the String into an Array like so:

```
var dataArray = allDataArray[x].split("</tr>");
```

What I'm trying is do is to use the following to get all the columns tags with content as a result. This only works for columns with an empty id:

```
var testRE = dataArray[x].match("<td ID=''>(.*)</td>");
```

Even though the following doesn't work, the format I want is something like this:

```
var testRE = dataArray[x].match("<td ID='(*)'>(.*)</td>");
```

***Is there a way to still display all the data, no matter what the id is?***

All knows help is appreciated.

Comment: You should use a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression) instead of a string

Comment: I've tried a couple of regular expressions, but this method is also sufficient for what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this regexp

```
var testRE = dataArray[xx].match("<td ID='([^']+)?'>(.*)</td>")
```

Comment: After the edit it works perfectly. Just had an error when looping. thanks for the quick reply :)